# Route in Codeigniter to hide Class Method

Tags: codeigniter, routes, class-method

Currently I have something like this
`$route['ourworks/client'] = "ourworks/ourwork_item/client";
$route['ourworks/portfolio'] = "ourworks/ourwork_item/portfolio";
$route['ourworks/casestudy'] = "ourworks/ourwork_item/casestudy";`

Is there anyway that I could make these 3 lines a a dynamic line?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
$route['ourworks/([a-z]+)'] = "ourworks/ourwork_item/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the other permitted chars use this:

```
$route['ourworks/(:any)'] = "ourworks/ourwork_item/$1";
```